# How to read values of the properties file in the powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a properties file properties.txt and I have the following values in it

```
filename = atc
 extension = zip

path = D:\root
and so on ..
```

so on I have some properties in the text file which I want to use these values in the .ps1 file

eg when I want to use the path in the .ps1 file I want the .ps1 file to read from the `properties.txt` file. I am trying above code  but it is not working . I wanted to read all the values

```
$props_file = Get-Content "D:\code"
$props = ConvertFrom-StringData ($properties.txt)
```

can any one please help me ?

Comment: Define "not working."  What *exact* behavior are you experiencing?  What behavior are you desiring?

Comment: Note that in a properties file a single '\' is an escape character, so you'll need double '\\' to have it be valid for Java and some other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
 $fileContents = get-content c:\path\properties.txt

 $properties = @{}

 foreach($line in $fileContents)
 {
     write-host $line
     # ,2 tells split to return two substrings (a single split) per line
     $words = $line.Split('=',2)
     $properties.add($words[0].Trim(), $words[1].Trim())
 }

 $properties
```

Then you can use the values like this

```
$properties.Extension
$properties.path
```

Comment: The challenge with using a Split is that there could be multiple '=' in one line, say for a nested URL that has a query string with additional `value=someval` statements. The syntax you gave for querying the values should work with the way he's parsed the file using `ConvertFrom-StringData`.

Comment: @dragon788 I approved your edit to include adding an argument to $line.Split().