# How to read the values of the 'details' tab of a file system obect's property sheet with powershell

Tags: powershell, properties, windows-10

Using Powershell, I want to create script to read various executable's version numbers and name. The info is listed on the details tab of the file's property sheet:

[image]

The basic file system object's properties do not seem to list them (using get-member). Also, have reviewed the following StackOverflow suggestions, that were not immediately helpful:

[stackoverflow ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498703/programatically-reading-the-details-tab-of-an-executable)
[Stackoverflow ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810617/how-to-read-values-of-the-properties-file-in-the-powershell-script)

Is it possible to do this with powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the `.VersionInfo` property of the target executable's [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instance, as reported by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) or [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item), contains the information of interest:

```
$exeFile = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'
(Get-ChildItem $exeFile).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

To see *all* available properties:

```
$exeFile = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'
(Get-ChildItem $exeFile).VersionInfo | Format-List *
```

---

Note that a different approach is required if *different kinds of properties* are to be extracted from files, such as photo-related metadata from image files - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52593094/45375).